# Is a functor which has a left adjoint which is also its right adjoint an equivalence ?

Tags: ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors, examples

I am looking for a counter-example of two functors F : C -> D and G : D->C such that

1) F is left adjoint to G

2) F is right adjoint to G

3) F is not an equivalence (ie F is not a quasi-inverse of G)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer of Ben Webster, can be made easier. Consider the functor F : (A-mod) -> (A-mod) which maps any A-module on (0). Then, F is a left adjoint to F ; and so, is a also a right adjoint to F. This is clear because for all A-modules N, M, one has Hom_A(0,N)=Hom_A(M,0). But, F is not an equivalence.

Answer (score 31):

There are lots of examples.  Here's what I think is in some sense the minimal one.

Let $C$ be the terminal category $\mathbf{1}$ (one object, and only the identity arrow).  Then for any category $D$, a left adjoint to the unique functor $G: D \to \mathbf{1}$ is an initial object of $D$, and a right adjoint is a terminal object.  So, we're looking for a category $D$ that has a zero object (one that is both initial and terminal), but is not equivalent to the terminal category.

There are plenty of such categories $D$, e.g. $\mathbf{Vect}$.  But I guess the minimal one is the category $D$ generated by a split epimorphism.  In other words, it consists of two objects, $0$ and $d$, and non-identity arrows
$$
p: d \to 0, \ \ \ i: 0 \to d, \ \ \ ip: d \to d,
$$
satisfying $pi = 1_0$.  Then $0$ is a zero object but $D$ is not equivalent to the terminal category.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, there are many such functors.  They are usually called "biadjoint." A good example is tensor product with a vector space $V$ in the category of finite dimensional vector spaces.  This is actually adjoint to itself.

This is a little funny since to find this adjunction you have to pick an isomorphism $V\cong V^*$, but that's OK; adjunction of functors only makes sense up to isomorphism anyways.

Another good example is induction and restriction for an inclusion of finite groups.

Comment: More generally, tensoring with any object of a symmetric monoidal category which is dualizable but not invertible.

Answer (score 4):

A pair of functors with this property where called Frobenius functors in 
S. Caenepeel, G. Militaru and S. Zhu, Doi-Hopf modules,
Yetter-Drinfel'd modules and Frobenius type properties, {\sl
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.}  {\bf 349} (1997), 4311--4342.

And main examples are given for cateogory o generalized Hopf modules, Yetter-Drinfel'd modules.

A detalied study of the you can find in :

S. Caenepeel, G. Militaru and Shenglin Zhu, {Frobenius Separable
Functors for Generalized Module Categories and Nonlinear
Equations}, {\sl Lect. Notes Math.} {\bf 1787} Springer Verlag,
Berlin, 2002.

Cheers! 
Gigel Militaru

Answer (score 2):

An adjunction of the form $(G\dashv F\dashv G)$ is called an **ambidextrous adjunction**. An example is any situation when the limit and colimit of a given diagram $D\colon\mathcal{I}\to\mathcal{C}$ on a category $\mathcal{C}$ coincide, as happens with e.g. [biproducts](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/biproduct). $\infty$-categorical examples include the recent papers on ambidexterity in chromatic homotopy theory, such as:

1. [Ambidexterity in $K(n)$-Local Stable Homotopy Theory (this links directly to a pdf)](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/Ambidexterity.pdf);
2. [Ambidexterity in Chromatic Homotopy Theory, arXiv:1811.02057](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.02057).

See also this year's [Talbot workshop](https://math.mit.edu/conferences/talbot/) or the [Juvitop Fall 2018 seminar](https://math.mit.edu/juvitop/pastseminars/2018_Fall.html), where you'll find some notes about the Hopkins–Lurie paper.

Extra links with more $1$-categorical examples:

1. [nLab page on ambidextrous adjunctions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ambidextrous+adjunction);
2. [MathUnderflow question on simple examples of ambidextrous adjunctions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382813/simple-examples-of-ambidextrous-adjunctions-and-their-frobenius-monads).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Misread the question

Take $j:U\to X$ an immersion of topological spaces. Then the restriction of sheaves of $A$-modules $j^* : Sh(X,A)\to Sh(U,A)$ has a right adjoint $j_*$ and a left adjoint $j_!$ (extension by 0).

Comment: Are there any examples where those are the same?  Seem unlikely.  You don't seem to have read the question very carefully.

Comment: I misread the question in the same way due to the title, which I now fixed.

Comment: These coincide when the embedding is also closed, for example the embedding of a connected component.

Comment: @JonathanWise what is meant by an immersion of topological spaces?